# PHP Parse JSON into HTML Table

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I am trying to convert a JSON array into an HTML table using PHP. But the problem is, this data can change with each request.
It means the JSON can contain more or less arrays and/or also different names associated.

Let's say,I have 2 different JSON requests:

```
$request_1 = '{
  "Hemograma": {
    "Eritrócitos": "5.13 x10¹2/L",
    "Hemoglobina": "16.6 g/dL",
    "Hematócrito": "49.1%",
    "Vol. Glob. Médio (VGM)": "96 fL",
    "Hgb. Glob. Média (HGM)": "32 pg",
    "Conc. Hgb. Glob. Média (CHGM)": "34 g/dL",
    "RDW (índice distrib. eritrocit.)": "12.7%"
  },
  "Leucograma": {
    "Leucócitos": "8.74 x10⁹/L",
    "-Neutrófilos": "5.28 x10⁹/L",
    "-Eosinófilos": "0.56 x10⁹/L",
    "-Basófilos": "0.05 x10⁹/L",
    "-Linfócitos": "2.32 x10⁹/L",
    "-Monócitos": "0.53 x10⁹/L"
  },
  "Plaquetas": {
    "-Plaquetas": "203 x10⁹/L",
    "-VPM (vol. plaq. médio)": "10.7 fL"
  }
}';

$request_2 = '{
  "URINA II (Exame Sumário da Urina)": {
    "Cor": "Amarela",
    "Aspecto": "Límpido",
    "Densidade": "1.021",
    "pH": "7.0",
    "Proteínas": "Vestígios",
    "Glucose": "Negativo",
    "Corpos Cetónicos": "Negativo",
    "Urobilinogénio": "Negativo",
    "Bilirrubina": "Negativo",
    "Nitritos": "Negativo",
    "Esterase leucocitária (Leucócitos)": "+ +",
    "Hemoglobina": "+ +"
  },
  "Exame do Sedimento": {
    "Células Epiteliais": "0-2/campo",
    "Leucócitos": 15 - 25 /campo,
    "   Eritrócitos ":"15-25/campo"
  },
  "Urina, Exame Microbiológico (Urocultura)": {
    "Células epiteliais":"0-2/campo", 
    "Leucócitos":"15 - 25/campo", 
    "Eritrócitos":"15-25/campo"
  },
  "Ex. Directo Gram":"Negativo", 
  "URINA E DOSEAMENTOS URINÁRIOS": {
    "Ex. Cultural Resultado":"Negativo"
  }
}';
```

Currently, I have the following code to parse the json into html table:

```
$obj = json_decode($request_1, true);
    
echo '<table>';
echo '<thead><tr>';
foreach ($obj as $section => $values) {
  foreach ($values as $name => $result) {
    echo "<th>{$section}/{$name}</th>";
  }
}
echo '</tr></thead>';
echo '<tbody><tr>';
foreach ($obj as $values) {
  foreach ($values as $result) {
    echo "<td>{$result}</td>";
  }
}
echo '</tr></tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

This code is working fine for the first json request ($request_1), **although** if we try the second json request mention in the code ($request_2), the same it is giving the following error:

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 64

> Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 71

Expected html sample result:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hemograma/Eritrócitos</th>
      <th>Hemograma/Hemoglobina</th>
      <th>Hemograma/Hematócrito</th>
      <th>Hemograma/Vol. Glob. Médio (VGM)</th>
      <th>Hemograma/Hgb. Glob. Média (HGM)</th>
      <th>Hemograma/Conc. Hgb. Glob. Média (CHGM)</th>
      <th>Hemograma/RDW (índice distrib. eritrocit.)</th>
      <th>Leucograma/Leucócitos</th>
      <th>Leucograma/-Neutrófilos</th>
      <th>Leucograma/-Eosinófilos</th>
      <th>Leucograma/-Basófilos</th>
      <th>Leucograma/-Linfócitos</th>
      <th>Leucograma/-Monócitos</th>
      <th>Plaquetas/-Plaquetas</th>
      <th>Plaquetas/-VPM (vol. plaq. médio)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>5.13 x10¹2/L</td>
      <td>16.6 g/dL</td>
      <td>49.1%</td>
      <td>96 fL</td>
      <td>32 pg</td>
      <td>34 g/dL</td>
      <td>12.7%</td>
      <td>8.74 x10⁹/L</td>
      <td>5.28 x10⁹/L</td>
      <td>0.56 x10⁹/L</td>
      <td>0.05 x10⁹/L</td>
      <td>2.32 x10⁹/L</td>
      <td>0.53 x10⁹/L</td>
      <td>203 x10⁹/L</td>
      <td>10.7 fL</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I fix this? cheers

Comment: Remember that there are two parts here: (1) parsing JSON into a PHP data structure, and (2) turning that data structure into HTML. One of those is a solved problem, simply being `json_decode`. So your problem has essentially "nothing" to do with JSON, that part's not the problem. So phrase the problem in terms of what _is_: you have a nested PHP associative array, show that, and explain what are you're trying to do with that instead.

Comment: That HTML sample is incomprehensible as is. Some better formatting would go a long way in making sure we understand what the goal is. Essentially you'll just need to focus on how to turn a specific array structure into a specific HTML structure. A small code sample should be enough for that.

Comment: For starters, your `$request_2` does not contain valid JSON - `"Leucócitos": 15 - 25 /campo,` - double quotes around the value are missing here.

Comment: And `"Ex. Directo Gram":"Negativo",` is just a string property on the top level - yet you are trying to loop over it the same as you do with the ones that are actually objects (resp. arrays, after parsing with second parameter set to true.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) First loop over that array for creating `<th><th>` data.

b) Inside the loop check the value(child) is an array or a simple string.

c) If it is an array then use `arra_keys()` to get all the keys of this child otherwise you are going to use this child value directly.

d) Create the `<th></th>` values by concatenating main keys with child keys using `/`

e) Now loop over the array again for creating `<td><td>` data.

f) Inside the loop check the value(child) is an array or a simple string.

g) If it is an array then loop over it and create `<td></td>` data by using values.

h) If it is a simple string then directly create `<td><td>` using the value.

Working snippet:

```
<?php
$obj = json_decode($request_2, true);
?>
<table>
    <thead>
    <?php foreach($obj as $key=>$values){
    if(is_array($values)){
    ?>
        <?php foreach(array_keys($values) as $val){?>
            <th><?php echo $key.'/'.$val;?></th>        
        <?php }?>
    <?php }else{?>
        <th><?php echo $key;?></th>
    <?php }}?>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($obj as $key=>$values){
            if(is_array($values)){
            ?>
                <?php foreach($values as $val){?>
                    <td><?php echo $val;?></td>     
                <?php }?>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <td><?php echo $values;?></td>
            <?php }} ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/4Cq7A And https://3v4l.org/5JFoo

Note:  `$request_2` in your question is not a valid JSON, I have made it valid in my answer by adding missing quotes around `"Leucócitos": 15 - 25 /campo,`. I hope it's a typo mistake in your question.